# Преобразование именованного массива без использования циклов

Tags: php

Есть такой исходный массив:

```
$input = [
    'id_1' => 'status_1',
    'id_2' => 'status_3',
    'id_3' => 'status_1',
    'id_4' => 'status_2',
    'id_5' => 'status_2',
    'id_6' => 'status_1',
    'id_7' => 'status_3',
    'id_8' => 'status_1',
    'id_9' => 'status_2',
    'id_10' => 'status_4',
    'id_11' => 'status_4',
    'id_12' => 'status_3',
    'id_13' => 'status_1',
    'id_14' => 'status_2',
    'id_15' => 'status_1',
    'id_16' => 'status_3',
];
```

Можно ли без использования циклов, **используя только нативные PHP функции** преобразовать его к массиву такой структуры:

```
$output = [
    'status_1' => [
        0 => 'id_1',
        1 => 'id_3',
        2 => 'id_6',
        3 => 'id_8',
        4 => 'id_13',
        5 => 'id_15',
    ],
    'status_3' => [
        0 => 'id_2',
        1 => 'id_7',
        2 => 'id_12',
        3 => 'id_16',
    ],
    'status_2' => [
        0 => 'id_4',
        1 => 'id_5',
        2 => 'id_9',
        3 => 'id_14',
    ],
    'status_4' => [
        0 => 'id_10',
        1 => 'id_11',
    ],
];
```

Порядок следования элементов роли не играет.

Comment: А что страшного в циклах?

Comment: С циклами - слишком банально)

Comment: Ну тогда разбирайтесь что вам в ответе написали. И потом еще через пару месяцев вернитесь к этому коду и попробуйте понять что тут происходит.

Comment: @u_mulder Предложите более понятный, более быстрый вариант. Минусовать все умеют)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$input = [
    'id_1' => 'status_1',
    'id_2' => 'status_3',
    'id_3' => 'status_1',
    'id_4' => 'status_2',
    'id_5' => 'status_2',
    'id_6' => 'status_1',
    'id_7' => 'status_3',
    'id_8' => 'status_1',
    'id_9' => 'status_2',
    'id_10' => 'status_4',
    'id_11' => 'status_4',
    'id_12' => 'status_3',
    'id_13' => 'status_1',
    'id_14' => 'status_2',
    'id_15' => 'status_1',
    'id_16' => 'status_3',
];


$output = array_combine(
    array_unique(
        array_values($input)
    ), array_map(
        function($entry) use ($input) {
            return array_keys(
                array_filter($input, function ($item) use ($entry) {
                    return $item === $entry;
                })
            );
        }, array_unique(
            array_values($input)
        )
    )
);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: И сравните затем с циклом в 5 строк.

Comment: @u_mulder Ну, условие задачи "без циклов". Топикстартер может конечно протестировать скорость на большом объёме обоих решений. Не факт, что нативные функции быстрее

Comment: Да дело не в скорости, дело в понимании кода. Если писать в стол то такое можно конечно забыть. Но если писать в продакшен, то надо сразу заворачивать.

Comment: ему явно не в продакшен. либо на спор, либо - не дай бог - на собеседование.

Answer (score 0):

Не все так страшно

```
$input = [
    'id_1' => 'status_1',
    'id_2' => 'status_3',
    'id_3' => 'status_1',
    'id_4' => 'status_2',
    'id_5' => 'status_2',
    'id_6' => 'status_1',
    'id_7' => 'status_3',
    'id_8' => 'status_1',
    'id_9' => 'status_2',
    'id_10' => 'status_4',
    'id_11' => 'status_4',
    'id_12' => 'status_3',
    'id_13' => 'status_1',
    'id_14' => 'status_2',
    'id_15' => 'status_1',
    'id_16' => 'status_3',
];

$output = array();

array_walk($input, function ($value, $key) use (&$output){
    if(!isset($output[$value])) $output[$value] = [];
    $output[$value][] = $key;
    return $value;
});

var_dump($output);
```

Только надо понимать, что под капотом там тот-же цикл.